# How to use Apache derby in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, derby

I have downloaded the Apache derby files from their website but derby JAR file wasn't available there. Eclipse is showing this error -

> Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: derby.jar.

Comment: When you download Derby from the Apache site, you get a tar/zip file which contains multiple jars. `derby.jar` is just one of those jars. After you unzip/un-tar the distribution from Apache, you will find the `derby.jar` in the results. Is that where you got confused?

Answer (score 0):

Download jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby/10.13.1.1).

**Advise**

Create **maven** Project,
Maven is a project management and comprehension tool that provides developers a complete build lifecycle framework
[maven](https://maven.apache.org/)
[maven](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/)